# HTTP POST request from Android App denied on Domain but works using IP address‏

Tags: dns, hosting

I'm trying to send a HTTP POST request to a PHP file on my web hosting server from my Android app.

That request contains the data from the app and is validated or saved on the server and then the PHP file sends a JSON response which is received by the Android device and the actions are taken accordingly like logging in or registering etc.

Now the problem that has arisen is that till now I didn't have a paid DOMAIN instead only a HOSTING service. That Hosting Service gave me a Server IP address to access the Index.php file I had uploaded.

So in my Android code I had written the url to be connected as http://10x.xxx.xx.xx/index.php/
and the request and response were working totally fine.

Now I have purchased a Domain name from Godaddy.com and I'm forwarding that domain name to the Server IP I had and when I open it in browser it's working perfectly fine. And so I changed the ip on which the request should be sent in my Android code to http://www.sampleurl.com/index.php/

This is my index.php file

```
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
// get tag
$tag = $_POST['tag'];
//do other authorization stuff
}
else
 echo "Access Denied";
```

**Now the problem is when I'm using the Server Ip address to connect it goes into the if block and functions correctly. But when I use the Domain name it always returns Access Denied.**

The Logcat shows:

```
    03-18 02:59:08.780: E/JSON(30892): Access Deniedn
    03-18 02:59:08.780: E/JSON Parser(30892): Error parsing data        org.json.JSONException: Value Access of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
    03-18 02:59:08.780: W/System.err(30892): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Now I don't know how a letter 'n' is appended after 'Access denied' neither why the request is not being served correctly.

P.S. I have used forwarding instead of updating the NS at the domain. Can that possibly be causing the issue?

Comment: Could you please share the Android code where you build the request

Comment: Your logcat prints the server reply and crashes trying to interpret `Access Denied` as JSON. Not sure how to interpret your last sentence "Now I don't ...".

Comment: uhm, waiting for your reply but what I actually want to know is if your android actually does a `post`, `put` or `get` request. You might find that out via php or in your server log.

Comment: @Giszmo I have used forwarding at my domain instead of using name servers. Can that possibly be a reason?

Comment: Check your server log and you will see what reaches your server but forwarding sounds wrong. It should probably be an `A` record.

Comment: The android part looks fine. Long, complicated but fine. For this post, only the first try block is relevant but after changing your DNS entry you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the DNS being configured to forward, your post-request got lost. Check your server logs. You need to set it to be a `type A` record.